# I want to input data (10 Players&Scores) in the main class, How can I call the void " ScoresList::add(const GameEntry& e) "?

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

### I  find it difficult to call add function. Please help me call the add function and input scores and players.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
```

---

```
class GameEntry                           
{
    private:
        string playerName;                 
        int playerScore;                    
        GameEntry*next;                    
        friend class ScoresList;           
    public:
        void setData(const string &name, int score )             
            {                                                    
            playerName = name;                                  
            playerScore = score;
            }
};

class ScoresList                                                
{
    public:
        ScoresList();                                                    //constructor to assign maxEnt
        void add(const GameEntry& e);                                  
        void remove(int i);                                             
        void removeLast();                                               
        void printEntries() ;                                               
        bool empty() const;                                              

    private:                                                        


        GameEntry*headNode;                                         
        int scoreCounter;                                           
};
```

### This is the Add Function I need to call in the main class.

- void ScoresList::add(const GameEntry& e)

  void ScoresList::add(const GameEntry& e)
  {
  GameEntry*buffNode = new GameEntry;
  buffNode->playerName = e.playerName;
  buffNode->playerScore = e.playerScore;
  buffNode->next = NULL;

  ```
   if(headNode == NULL)                 
       {
       headNode = buffNode;             
       scoreCounter++;                 
       }
   else                        
       {

       if(e.playerScore > headNode->playerScore)  
           {
           buffNode->next = headNode;               
           headNode = buffNode;
           scoreCounter++;                             
           }

       else                                         
           {

           GameEntry *tempNode;                        
           tempNode = headNode;                              
           while(tempNode->next != NULL)                   
               {
               if(tempNode->playerScore > buffNode-> playerScore && buffNode-> playerScore >= tempNode->next->playerScore)             
               {

               buffNode->next = tempNode->next;            
               tempNode->next = buffNode;
               scoreCounter++;                            
               }
               tempNode = tempNode->next;                   
               }

           if(tempNode->playerScore >= buffNode-> playerScore)          
               {
               cout << "\n Sorry! the Score is insufficient to make it to the top 10.";              
               }

           else                                                    
               {
               tempNode -> playerName = e.playerName;                      
               tempNode -> playerScore = e.playerScore;
               scoreCounter++;     
               }
           }
       }
   if(scoreCounter >= 11) 
   removeLast();
  ```

  }
  }

### *** How can I call add function input 10 Scores and Name.***

int  main()
{

```
        return 0;
    }
```

## Edit * Thanks, I now have an answer.

int  main()
{

```
        cout<<"Enter Player's Name : "; 
        cin>>playerName;
        cout<<"Enter Player's Score : "; 
        cin>>playerScore;
        GE.setData(playerName,playerScore); 
        GE.displays();   
        sl.add(GE);
```

return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Get inputs from `main` function  and pass that  values to functions in class ,  using calling statement of that function

Example :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Student 
{
    private :
          string name;
          int student_id;

    public : 
            void getData(string name,student_id)
            {     
                   this->name=name;
                   this->student_id=student_id;

             }
              
             void display ()
             {
                    cout<<"STUDENT NAME : "<<name<<endl;
                    cout<<"STUDWNT ID : "<<student_id<<endl;
             }
};

int main()
{
    Student s1; // Student object 

    string name; 
    int id;
     
    cout<<"Enter Student Name : "; //get input here
    cin>>name;

     cout<<"Enter Student ID : "; //get input here
     cin>>id;

     s1.getData(name,id);  // pass values to getData function 
     s1.display();. // display values

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tried to do exactly as what you have said and was able to get the input of Player's name and And Player's score in the Game Entry, but how can I pass it to the " void ScoresList::add(const GameEntry& e)      ? " Because if do it on my own way it just says" errorr no matching funcion to call." I don't know how to call the add function or pass the data from GameEntry to add function.. Please help.

Comment: How can I call the add function, I find it difficult to understand operation overloading,

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use loop and constructors for get 10 inputs and pass to class.create 10 objects in array and pass values to constructor

Example :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Student 
{
private :
      string name;
      int student_id;

public : 
        Student (string name,int student_id)
        {     
               this->name=name;
               this->student_id=student_id;
         }          
         void display ()
         {
              cout<<"NAME : "<<name<<endl;
                cout<<"ID : "<<student_id<<endl;
         }
};




int main()
{
string name; 
int id;
for(int c=0;c<=9;c++)
{
      cout<<"Enter Student Name : ";
      cin>>name; //get input here
      cout<<"Enter Student ID : "; 
      cin>>id; //get input here

      Student s[c](name,id);  //student object array 

        s[c].display();. // display values
 }

       return 0;
 }
```